# Option Strict Late Binding error issue

Tags: .net, vb.net, object, casting, shell32

The option Strict throws me an error of ***Late Binding***, I always cast the objects to the proper type but in this specific case I don't know how to cast this object.

The warning occurs in the instruction `Shell.ToggleDesktop()`

Here is the code:

```
''' <summary>
''' "Shell" CLASSID.
''' MSDN Documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776890%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
''' </summary>
Private Shared ReadOnly CLSIDShell As New Guid("13709620-C279-11CE-A49E-444553540000")

''' <summary>
''' Gets the objects in the Shell.
''' Methods are provided to control the Shell and to execute commands within the Shell.
''' There are also methods to obtain other Shell-related objects.
''' MSDN Documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774094%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
''' </summary>
Private Shared ReadOnly Property Shell As Object
    Get
        If _Shell Is Nothing Then
            _Shell = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(CLSIDShell))
            Return _Shell
        Else
            Return _Shell
        End If
    End Get
End Property
Private Shared _Shell As Object = Nothing

''' <summary>
''' Shows or hides the desktop.
''' </summary>
Friend Shared Sub ToggleDesktop()

    Shell.ToggleDesktop()

End Sub
```

Comment: What type has that `ToggleDesktop` method as a member?

Comment: I don't know, all the info that I have is commented in the code, and this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg537747%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: I preffer to keep the `Activator.CreateInstance` usage to avoid referencing in the project unneeded dlls like the COM Object: `Microsoft Shell And Controls Automation` which is used to perform the same task in the same way (because Is the same), I think the type is called "Shell" or "Shell32" from that COM.

Comment: `Project -> Properties -> Compile` in the list, change the result of Late Binding to "Warning".  This allows you to use Object in cases when you are sure it is ok and you know what you are doing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get this error because the type `Object` do not expose a method named `ToggleDesktop`.

You can set `Option Strict Off` for this code file, or create a wrapper and use reflection to invoke the method.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I couldn't just cast the object to a type that exposes that method to solve it?, is possibly in this circunstances?

Comment: If there's a .net assembly you can reference then yes. If not, then no.

Comment: @ElektroStudios Actually, I did find a reference. It's named `Microsoft Shell Controls And Automation`. Looks like you need to create an instance of `Shell32.Shell`. This interface exposes the `ToggleDesktop` method.